# Issues with Reach router Nested routes

Tags: reactjs, reach-router

i am having trouble with reach router nested routes, I am trying to navigate to / and render page2, but I am stuck on "/" homepage the same page when the route changes to //

```
<Appjs>
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Homepage from "./Components/Homepage";
import Details from "./Components/Details";



function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <Homepage path="/">
          <Details path="details" />
        </Homepage>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import React, { Component, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import styled, { isStyledComponent } from "styled-components";
import NavLink from "./NavLink";
import { Link } from "@reach/router";

const Homepage = () => {
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className={"container"}>
        <Styleddiv>
          <h2>Select an Account</h2>
          <div style={{ padding: 0 }}>
            {Object.values(users).map((item) => (
              <Link to={`details/${item.name}`}>
                <img src={item.profilepicture} alt="Girl in a jacket"></img>
                <span>{item.name}</span>
              </Link>
            ))}
          </div>
        </Styleddiv>
      </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default Homepage;
```

Am I missing something while structuring the routes inside the router, Kindly help me

So in Homepage If i click on any Link the route changes to /details but the details page fails to render

https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-hill-j5gmy?file=/src/Homepage.js

Comment: Please align your routing structure to the [React Router DOM Docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start/1st-example-basic-routing)

Comment: it wont be applicable , I am using reach router

Answer (score 0):

Did you miss your `Router` import on your `App.js` file?

```
import React from "react";
import { Router, Link } from "@reach/router";

import Homepage from "./Homepage";
import Details from "./Details";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <nav>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        <Link to="dashboard">Detail</Link>
      </nav>
      <Router>
        <Homepage path="/" />
        <Details path="dashboard" />
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Edit: [Code Sand Box](https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-framework-u671s?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I use nested routes

[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-nested-router-wt3hk?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

In order to nest routes you need to place them in the child component of the route.

The `render` prop is used instead of `component` because it stops the inline functional component from being remounted every render, [see explanation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func).

The match object contains the information about how a route matched the URL, so we can have a nested route using the `url` property which gives us the matched portion of the URL, [see explanation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match).

Comment: The solution you gave was with respect to react router, is there any similar explanation for reach router?

Comment: Try this https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-cloud-m6tbg?file=/src/Page1.jsx, also make sure you receive props on your Homepage component and render it with {props.children}

Comment: The solution you gave seems to work but is there any ways to render child component based  on routes, for exaple suppose the details component has three children , I want to render first two child in /details page and render the third child in /details/post page

Comment: import the two components and render them inside details, and the third one keep it as path to "posts". you can check the solution again, I've updated it.

Comment: Yeas, I am able to achieve the desired result, however child components are wrapped under a tabindex div which messes my whole css, trying to find a way around it, Your help was crucial,appreciate it, Thank you